# Poisson Conditional probability distribution

Tags: probability

I will be glad to get some help with this one.

Volcano A erupt by poisson distribution with expected value of 1 eruption each year
Volcano B erupt by poisson distribution with expected value of 1 eruption each **half** year.

let $X_1$ be the number of eruption of Volcano A in the last year.
let $X_2$ be the number of eruption of Volcano A in the last **two** years.
let $W_1$ be the sum of eruption of Volcano A and Volcano B  in the last year.
let $W_2$ be the sum of eruption of Volcano A and Volcano B  in the last **two** years.

what is the distribution of $(X_1\mid W_1=3, W_2 = 6, X_2=2)$ ?

1.Poisson
2.Hypergeometric
3.Binomial
4.None of the above

from what I saw, it should be Hypergeometric, but I have no idea why? 
is there an easy way to eliminate the Binomial option?

I tried to find the values $X_1|...$ can get, and found they are 0,1,2. then I thought to look at the problem in an hypergeometric way : HG(N,D,n)

D = 2 eruptions of volcano A in the first year
N = 4 eruptions of Volcano A at total in the last two years
n = 2 max value of $X_1|...$

But Im not sure if I can do that consider all the conditions on $X_1$, and even if I can Im kind of stuck.

thanks.

Comment: What is X? What did you try?

Comment: What do you mean by $X=2$?  The random variables you list don't include one called $X$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: it should be $X_2$

Comment: In the absence of the conditions, what are the probabilities for $X_1=0,1,2$? How does Baynes rule modify this?